# C program: Modifying Airport simulation to have two runways

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and was going through a particular book called Data Structures and Program Design in C where I happened to come across a particular problem. The airport simulation problem for linked lists queues. I did understand the first implementation using one runway but i am stuck in the subsequent problem which asks to modify it to have two runways one for landing and one for takeoff only and compare the wait time results.
I am having trouble finding out how to incorporate it. 
Any help or suggestions would be strongly appreciated. 
I will add the code for the program below (the one with one runway)

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX 3
#define ARRIVE 0
#define DEPART 1

struct plane
{
    int id;
    int tm;
};

struct queue
{
    int count;
    int front;
    int rear;
    struct plane p[MAX];
};

void initqueue(struct queue*);
void addqueue(struct queue*, struct plane);
struct plane delqueue(struct queue*);
int size(struct queue);
int empty(struct queue);
int full(struct queue);

void initqueue(struct queue* pq)
{
    pq->count = 0;
    pq->front = 0;
    pq->rear = -1;
}

void addqueue(struct queue* pq, struct plane item)
{
    if (pq->count >= MAX)
    {
        printf("\nQueue is full.\n");
        return;
    }
    (pq->count)++;

    pq->rear = (pq->rear + 1) % MAX;
    pq->p[pq->rear] = item;
}

struct plane delqueue(struct queue* pq)
{
    struct plane p1;

    if (pq->count <= 0)
    {
        printf("\nQueue is empty.\n");
        p1.id = 0;
        p1.tm = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        (pq->count)--;
        p1 = pq->p[pq->front];
        pq->front = (pq->front + 1) % MAX;
    }
    return p1;
}

int size(struct queue q)
{
    return q.count;
}

int empty(struct queue q)
{
    return (q.count <= 0);
}

int full(struct queue q)
{
    return (q.count >= MAX);
}

struct airport
{
    struct queue landing;
    struct queue takeoff;
    struct queue* pl;
    struct queue* pt;
    int idletime;
    int landwait, takeoffwait;
    int nland, nplanes, nrefuse, ntakeoff;
    struct plane pln;
};

void initairport(struct airport*);
void start(int*, double*, double*);
void newplane(struct airport*, int, int);
void refuse(struct airport*, int);
void land(struct airport*, struct plane, int);
void fly(struct airport*, struct plane, int);
void idle(struct airport*, int);
void conclude(struct airport*, int);
int randomnumber(double);
void apaddqueue(struct airport*, char);
struct plane apdelqueue(struct airport*, char);
int apsize(struct airport, char);
int apfull(struct airport, char);
int apempty(struct airport, char);
void myrandomize();

void initairport(struct airport* ap)
{
    initqueue(&(ap->landing));
    initqueue(&(ap->takeoff));

    ap->pl = &(ap->landing);
    ap->pt = &(ap->takeoff);
    ap->nplanes = ap->nland = ap->ntakeoff = ap->nrefuse = 0;
    ap->landwait = ap->takeoffwait = ap->idletime = 0;
}

void start(int* endtime, double* expectarrive, double* expectdepart)
{
    int flag = 0;
    char wish;

    printf("\nProgram that simulates an airport with only one runway.\n");
    printf("One plane can land or depart in each unit of time.\n");
    printf("Up to %d planes can be waiting to land or take off at any time.\n", MAX);
    printf("How many units of time will the simulation run?");
    scanf("%d", endtime);
    myrandomize();
    do
    {
        printf("\nExpected number of arrivals per unit time? ");
        scanf("%lf", expectarrive);
        printf("\nExpected number of departures per unit time? ");
        scanf("%lf", expectdepart);

        if (*expectarrive < 0.0 || *expectdepart < 0.0)
        {
            printf("These numbers must be nonnegative.\n");
            flag = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (*expectarrive + *expectdepart > 1.0)
            {
                printf("The airport will become saturated. Read new numbers? ");
                scanf(" %c", &wish);
                if (tolower(wish) == 'y')
                    flag = 0;
                else
                    flag = 1;
            }
            else
                flag = 1;
        }
    } while (flag == 0);
}

void newplane(struct airport* ap, int curtime, int action)
{
    (ap->nplanes)++;
    ap->pln.id = ap->nplanes;
    ap->pln.tm = curtime;

    switch (action)
    {
    case ARRIVE:
        printf("\n");
        printf("Plane %d ready to land.\n", ap->nplanes);
        break;

    case DEPART:
        printf("\nPlane %d ready to take off.\n", ap->nplanes);
        break;
    }
}

void refuse(struct airport* ap, int action)
{
    switch (action)
    {
    case ARRIVE:

        printf("\tplane  %d directed to another airport.\n", ap->pln.id);
        break;

    case DEPART:

        printf("\tplane %d told to try later.\n", ap->pln.id);
        break;
    }
    (ap->nrefuse)++;
}

void land(struct airport* ap, struct plane pl, int curtime)
{
    int wait;

    wait = curtime - pl.tm;
    printf("%d: Plane %d landed ", curtime, pl.id);
    printf("in queue %d units \n", wait);
    (ap->nland)++;
    (ap->landwait) += wait;
}

void fly(struct airport* ap, struct plane pl, int curtime)
{
    int wait;

    wait = curtime - pl.tm;
    printf("%d: Plane %d took off ", curtime, pl.id);
    printf("in queue %d units \n", wait);
    (ap->ntakeoff)++;
    (ap->takeoffwait) += wait;
}

void idle(struct airport* ap, int curtime)
{
    printf("%d: Runway is idle.\n", curtime);
    ap->idletime++;
}

void conclude(struct airport* ap, int endtime)
{
    printf("\tSimulation has concluded after %d units.\n", endtime);
    printf("\tTotal number of planes processed: %d\n", ap->nplanes);
    printf("\tNumber of planes landed: %d\n", ap->nland);
    printf("\tNumber of planes taken off: %d\n", ap->ntakeoff);
    printf("\tNumber of planes refused use: %d\n", ap->nrefuse);
    printf("\tNumber left ready to land: %d\n", apsize(*ap, 'l'));
    printf("\tNumber left ready to take off: %d\n", apsize(*ap, 't'));

    if (endtime > 0)
        printf("\tPercentage of time runway idle: %lf \n", ((double)ap->idletime / endtime) * 100.0);

    if (ap->nland > 0)
        printf("\tAverage wait time to land: %lf \n", ((double)ap->landwait / ap->nland));

    if (ap->ntakeoff > 0)
        printf("\tAverage wait time to take off: %lf \n", ((double)ap->takeoffwait / ap->ntakeoff));
}

int randomnumber(double expectedvalue)
{
    int n = 0; //counter of iteration
    double limit;
    double x;  //pseudo random number
    limit = exp(-expectedvalue);
    x = rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
    while (x > limit) {
        n++;
        x *= rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
    }
    return n;
}

void apaddqueue(struct airport* ap, char type)
{
    switch (tolower(type))
    {
    case'l':
        addqueue(ap->pl, ap->pln);
        break;

    case't':
        addqueue(ap->pt, ap->pln);
        break;
    }
}

struct plane apdelqueue(struct airport* ap, char type)
{
    struct plane p1;

    switch (tolower(type))
    {
    case'l':
        p1 = delqueue(ap->pl);
        break;

    case't':
        p1 = delqueue(ap->pl);
        break;
    }

    return p1;
}

int apsize(struct airport ap, char type)
{
    switch (tolower(type))
    {
    case'l':
        return (size(*(ap.pl)));

    case't':
        return (size(*(ap.pt)));
    }

    return 0;
}

int apfull(struct airport ap, char type)
{
    switch (tolower(type))
    {
    case'l':
        return (full(*(ap.pl)));

    case't':
        return (full(*(ap.pt)));
    }

    return 0;
}

int apempty(struct airport ap, char type)
{
    switch (tolower(type))
    {
    case'l':
        return (empty(*(ap.pl)));

    case't':
        return (empty(*(ap.pt)));
    }

    return 0;
}

void myrandomize()
{
    srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL) % 10000));
}

void main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    struct airport a;
    int i, pri, curtime, endtime;
    double expectarrive, expectdepart;
    struct plane temp;
    int test;
    test = randomnumber(0.47);
    printf("%d", test);
    initairport(&a);

    start(&endtime, &expectarrive, &expectdepart);

    for (curtime = 1; curtime <= endtime; curtime++)
    {
        pri = randomnumber(expectarrive);

        for (i = 1; i <= pri; i++)
        {
            newplane(&a, curtime, ARRIVE);
            if (apfull(a, 'l'))
                refuse(&a, ARRIVE);
            else
                apaddqueue(&a, 'l');
        }

        pri = randomnumber(expectdepart);
        for (i = 1; i <= pri; i++)
        {
            newplane(&a, curtime, DEPART);
            if (apfull(a, 't'))
                refuse(&a, DEPART);
            else
                apaddqueue(&a, 't');
        }

        if (!(apempty(a, 'l')))
        {
            temp = apdelqueue(&a, 'l');
            land(&a, temp, curtime);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!(apempty(a, 't')))
            {
                temp = apdelqueue(&a, 't');
                fly(&a, temp, curtime);
            }
            else
                idle(&a, curtime);
        }
    }

    conclude(&a, endtime);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `initairport` you initialize two queues to handle the single runway's takeoff and landing queues.

The problem in this program is that you have a blind assumption.  That means the whole program believes that there is only one runway, so the runway details have never been addressed.

To fix this, you will have to create a new data structure, called a runway.

```
struct runway {
};
```

Each runway has a takeoff and landing queue that is independent of all the other runways.

```
struct runway {
    struct queue takeoff;
    struct queue landing;
};
```

So, you will need to update the airport too:

```
struct airport {
    struct queue takeoff; 
    struct queue landing;
    struct runway runway1;
    struct runway runway2;
    ...
};
```

At this point, you can see you'll need a new set of functions to handle the initialization of a runway, and you'll need to figure out if the whole-airport takeoff and landing queues should be a combination of the two runways, or if they should just be removed.  Also you will have to review the rest of the code for any sensible modifications.

Comment: yes this was very helpful, i was so overwhelmed trying to figure out how to modify this code in a minimal way that I forgot to see the very basis of the code.

Comment: @QubeStoo Glad to hear it helped.  Good luck!